# bxslider next button moves slide only half way

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using bxslider and for some reason isn't calculating the correct distance to move the individual tags when paging. I have set the wrapper and window to the same size as the entries and if you select the slider from the pager it does properly align. This happens in FF and Chrome.

Anyone else having similar issues?

```
$('#news').bxSlider({
auto: true,
pager: true,
pause: 5000,
wrapperClass: 'news-wrapper'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="news">
  <div>
    <h4 class="title">Title Four</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <h4 class="title">Title Four</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
        <h4 class="title">Title Four</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
        <h4 class="title">Title Four</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: No one is going to be able to help much without at least some of your code detailing the problem...

Comment: Sorry Update with code and screen shot...

Comment: Do you possibly have any CSS rules which are generalized enough where they would effect the width of the stage? eg. div{} or h4{}?  Is the visibity toggled (does it start off hidden and get shown using a jQuery trigger)?

Comment: Josh - Not that I can find. Everything works OK in IE but for some reason webkit don't like something....

Comment: I had something similar happen to my a couple of weeks ago, but i had the containing div hidden when the page loaded, so the module couldn't find the width.  In your case I'm not sure.  You could try adding definite widths to each of the divs which contain a "slide"

Comment: for me its happening only in chrome though FF runs it perfectly...